# Gstreamer + meson: Undefined reference to `gst_rtp_buffer_map'

Tags: gstreamer, meson-build

I am trying to add the code below to an existing application that uses GStreamer 1.22.1.
It compiles but gives a link error:

> /home/src/webrtc/gst/gst.c:99: undefined reference to `gst_rtp_buffer_map'

The code seems to be in [gst-plugins-base](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/main/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/gst-libs/gst/rtp/gstrtpbuffer.c?ref_type=heads), which Is enabled.
What am I missing?

This is the build command:

```
  meson \
    -Dbuildtype=release \
    -Drs=disabled \
    -Dtests=disabled \
    -Dexamples=disabled \
    -Drtsp_server=disabled \
    -Dges=disabled \
    -Dgst-examples=disabled \
    -Ddoc=disabled \
    -Dgtk_doc=disabled \
    -Dpython=disabled \
    -Dqt5=disabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-bad:openh264=disabled \
    -Dugly=${x264_flag} \
    -Dgpl=${x264_flag} \
    -Dlibav=enabled \
    -Dbase=enabled \
    -Dgood=enabled \
    -Dbad=enabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-good:rtp=enabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-base:ogg=disabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-base:vorbis=disabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-good:jpeg=disabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-good:lame=disabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-bad:rtp=enabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-bad:webrtc=enabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-bad:va=enabled \
    -Dgst-plugins-bad:dvb=disabled \
    -Ddevtools=disabled \
    --prefix=/opt/local/build/gst/ builddir && ninja -C builddir && ninja -C builddir install && ldconfig
```

And this is the new code:

```
#include <gst/rtp/gstrtpbuffer.h>
...
      if (gst_rtp_buffer_map (buffer, GST_MAP_READ, &rtp)) {
        rtptime = gst_rtp_buffer_get_timestamp (&rtp);
        seqnum = gst_rtp_buffer_get_seq (&rtp);
        gst_rtp_buffer_unmap (&rtp);
      }
```